# How can I best train my two animal companions for attack and utility?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, optimization, ranger, animals

I obtained two wolves from my [spell-less ranger](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/3rd-party-classes/kobold-press-open-design/spell-less-ranger) class using the [Additional Animal Companion](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/3rd-party-classes/kobold-press-open-design/spell-less-ranger/#TOC-Ranger-Talents) talent.
My ranger is level 4, with all feats (so far) from archery. I want to be more of a marksman-beastmaster guy so I took two wolves as animal companions. I want the first to be an aggressive, full attacking one and the second one to handle utility and role-playing functions, such as fetching items (burglar).
Any suggestions? I want some good feats and tricks for these two wolves. It's my first campaign and I'm a novice so I want some help.

Comment: Manolis jam, can you give more specific details about your level (or relevant range of levels) for this? Also, in the comments below you mentioned you aim for a ranged ranger - can you please edit your question to add those details and others which may be relevant (such as how many feats you are willing to spend on your wolves, how to split levels between them etc.)? I'm not sure this question is too opinion based (there are several optimization questions here, and normally the answers converge...), but it's a bit broad as it stands - adding those extra details may redeem it. Goodluck :)

Comment: Also, can you add a link to this "Spell-less Ranger" alternate class feature / archetype? I couldn't find it on d20pfsrd...

Comment: I have to split lvls for the wolfs?

Comment: Thanks for adding the link. Reading it showed me I was wrong - spell-lees ranger with the 'Additional Animal Companion' talent grants both of his companions the full benefit of his level - I confused it with the way the [beastmaster](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/3rd-party-classes/tripod-machine/beastmaster) archetype splits his levels between multiple companions - sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some of my recommendations for Feats / Tricks. For the Burglar wolf I recommend Fetch, Sneak and Flee. The Flee and Sneak are so that the wolf remains hidden and is capable of fleeing combat to avoid death. The combat wolf would depend on how you are playing Ranger, if you are going ranged I would recommend feats like Improved Trip (I do not know if your wolf meets the stat requirements). However if you are going melee combat then Outflank and Precise Strike are very handy, just remember to pick up the teamwork feat on your ranger.

**Animal Companion Feats:**

Outflank - Flanking grants a +4 to hit instead of +2 - http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/outflank-combat-teamwork

Boon Companion - Wolf is as if you were druid instead of ranger (+4 levels) - http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/boon-companion

Precise Strike (Teamwor) - If you decide to fight along side your wolf and flank this grants sneak attack damage with it  - http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/precise-strike-combat-teamwork

Power Attack / Dodge / Mobility / Spring Attack - Also good to pick up.

**Animal Tricks:**

Fetch (DC 15) The animal goes and gets something. If you do not point out a specific item, the animal fetches some random object.

Sneak (DC 15): The animal can be ordered to make Stealth checks in order to stay hidden and to continue using Stealth even when circumstances or its natural instincts would normally cause it to abandon secrecy.

Flee (DC 20): The animal attempts to run away or hide as best it can, returning only when its handler commands it to do so. Until such a command is received, the animal does its best to track its handler and any creatures with him or her, remaining hidden but within range of its sight or hearing. This trick is particularly useful for thieves and adventurers in that it allows the animal to evade capture, then return later to help free its friends.

Flank (DC 20): You can instruct an animal to attack a foe you point to and always attempt to be adjacent to (and threatening) that foe. If you or an ally is also threatening the foe, the animal attempts to flank the foe, if possible. It always takes attacks of opportunity. The animal must know the attack trick before it can learn this trick.

Comment: Isn't 'Boon Companion' a feat meant for the PC herself - not her companion?

Comment: Also, taking the *Attack* trick twice so the wolf can attack anything is useful. (I assume "Attack" doesn't appear in the list of tricks since it should be an obvious take [and a prerequisite to Flank])

Comment: Im playing my ranger with ranged weapon so the flank feats do not wrok i got the "friendly fire" feat.Also how Boon Companion works i mean when i apply it my pet has +4 lvl?Also for my burglar wolf how can i make him steal things how does that work?And lets say i give the command flee to one of my wolfs so it stays hidden and it comes when i say so  can it stay hidden while im in a city or something??Any advise on the options i have and can do with my "burglar" wolf or what i cant do.

Comment: Also improved trip requires 13 intelligence..

Comment: Yes that was why I said I do not know the stats of your wolf, and Boon Companion treats your companion as if you were a druid instead of a ranger, it gives it +4 levels. The stealing is role playing, you tell the gm that you command the wolf to fetch a particular item that you have interest in, the only rolling required that I know of is the handle animal check to teach the wolf the commands.

Comment: The reason is for role playing purposes, when I used animal companions my gm would specifically target them unless I made an effort or attempt to keep the weak one hidden. Also look up armor proficiency feats for your animal companion, if I am not mistaken they can use armor

Comment: The spell-less ranger's effective druid level is equal to his full spell-less ranger level.So im 4 lvl so are my wolfs.The feats i got on the first wolf is heavy armor and combat reflexes and on my burglar wolf combat reflexes and weaponfocus but i can change them should i use stealthy feat? if i want him to steal something or do something sneak its stealth right?

Comment: Ahh okay! I did not know what arch type you were using and was not aware of that ability. I would not bother with the feat than. Stealing would be a Sleight of Hand check opposed by a Perception check, the Stealth check would be made ahead of time if you plan on having your wolf enter a building or location without being noticed. Should your wolf be spotted, you could still make a sleight of hand to coin or seal the item without being noticed. Sleight of hand is also used to conceal weapons, you could have your burglar wolf conceal weapons for you.

Comment: I wouldn't take weapon focus unless you plan on him fighting. Combat Expertise is good, it can lead to feats such as Improved Feint. Skill focus is good, and also  A lot of the wolfs stealth will also come from your role playing and disguise / bluff / diplomacy checks. Example: Say you plan on keeping the attention of an audience while your wolf steals, you would make a Perform check to keep their attention or depending on how you execute it, it could also qualify as a bluff or diplomacy check opposed by a sense motive check. The purpose is to give your wolf bonuses to the Sleight of Hand.

Comment: So i use skill points to sleight of hand  and stealth and also have to distract people right?

Comment: You do not have to, it is one of the many ways that role playing helps influence the game. But yes, sleight of hand and stealth will be very good for your burglar wolf.